# Amazon SES duplicated emails

Tags: php, amazon-ses

I have a cronjob that runs every 5 minutes. That basically calls a function that calls another functions and if a condition is met, it will send emails. This cronjob is using a lock to avoid overlapping tasks.

My problem is that sometimes, sent emails are duplicated, and the number of duplications is not consistent. Like, twice it sent it x10, and once x2. And sometimes also works as expected, with no duplications!
I noticed that when duplications happen, is because I am sending a "big" batch of emails, the first one should have been around 180 emails, and 1800 was sent.
The second time, same.
But the third time, was 400ish emails instead of 200ish.

When the amount of emails are small, it works fine. When is bigger, it does these weird incosistent things.

I had a look at a pair of the duplicated emails and they have different Amazon IDs.

This is a problem that is happening in the live app but not in dev.

I've been checking in the code (PHP) how many times is the send email function being called and seems fine (with a variable increments every time the function is called).
Also, in dev, everytime the email is sent, a column with some data is added to the database (MYSQL) and nothing is duplicated in there.

My dev is set up with Docker containers, and one of the containers has the following cronjob:

```
*/5 * * * * flock -n /tmp/routines.lock /usr/bin/wget "http://nginx:80/api/cron/routines" --no-check-certificate --output-document=- >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Every 5 minutes I can see in the Nginx terminal that this is being called correctly and the lock file is being created.

I have thought that the duplication could have been caused because I call the send email function in a foreach loop? But I am not sure that makes much sense, because this only happens sometimes, and with different amount of duplications. And of course, the table I am looping through have unique data, they aren't repeated or anything. The structure of the foreach is something like this:

```
// Switch is used because they are different kind of emails
foreach( $rows as $row )
{
  if( Condition is met )
  {
    switch( Condition )
    {
      case null:
        // Code to update database
        // Code to send email
        break;
      case 1:
        // Code to update database
        // Code to send email
        break;
      case 2:
        // Code to update database
        // Code to send email
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd suspect your job takes longer than five minutes to run sometimes, and that you're marking all the rows as "done" at the end of the task. Check before sending *each* email, and update the "done" status in the database immediately.

Comment: I guess it could be possible that in some cases it can take more than 5 minutes.  I thought that by locking files, overlapping would not happen.
In the code, before I send the email, I update the database and then send the email so the next time this function runs, checks the database, and sends the email (or not).

Comment: That'd depend on how your locking works. File locks also won't help if you've got multiple load-balanced servers, either.

Comment: I would instrument the code to log the PID and PPID at the place where it sends an email (although messy to get more ancestry if there's a deep chain of processes here). That at least might tell you where in the chain the duplication is occurring. Although IMHO SES is great example of when NOT to use serverless.

Comment: Provide some code along with your question. It is likely that you have an issue with locking like @ceejayoz mentioned and showing us how it is implemented and explaining how you run it might help!

Comment: I added the cronjob code and the structure of the code that calls the send email function.